# Delete a Build Controller in TFS 2012

Tags: tfs

I configured a Build Controller for TFS 2012, and 2 Agents for that in a Virtual machine several month ago. Now I remove the virtual machine that contains **agents**, and when I want to delete the **build controller** from TFS, it shows this error message:

[image: Cannot delete build controller]

and also it doesn't show me the Agents to delete them.

[image: Build Configuration]

I want to know is there any way to delete the controller and reconfigure it again without accessing to the agents machine?

*if my question is not clear enough tell me to complete it.*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Open up visual studio 2012.  Navigate to Team Explorer - Builds (Ctrl 0,B).  There is an actions dropdown in the top left, click it and select Manage build controllers.

Comment: Wow! Ctrl+Zero+B or P or whatever rocked my day! (also works in VS2013)

Answer (score 1):

To remove a build server, login into your build server and open the build configuration. Then remove the agents. Afterwards you can de-register the build server.

I'm not 100 % sure whether ther is not another way, but this is how I removed a deprecated build server from a 2010 TFS installation.

Comment: I edit my question, actually it doesn't show me the agents to delete them.